# In Laravel view how to json_decode the URL

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I json_encode URL data before send it to database. Now I am retriving those data in view page. But I need to `json_decode` it to get url link smootly. But in some part of code I couldn't do it.

My foreach for the url json_decode(link) not working and returns laravel error. The error is: `Undefined variable: links (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)`

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($estates as $estate)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$estate->company_name}}</td>

            <?php
                $links = json_decode($estate->link); 
                $hrefs = "";
                foreach($links as $link){
                    $hrefs .= '<a href="'.$link.'" } target="_blank">{{$estate->name}}</a><br/>';
                }
                $hrefs .= "";
            ?>

            <td>{{$estate->address}}</td>
            <td>{{$estate->price}}</td>
            <td>{{$estate->hows_old}}</td>
            <td>{{$estate->extend}}</td>
            <td>{{$estate->rooms}}</td>
            <td>{{$estate->balcon_m2}}</td>
            <td>{{$estate->old}}</td>
            <td>{{$estate->entery}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

without json_decode `estate->link` is like this:

```
`http://localhost/[%22https:////www.31sumai.com//pid//about//%22,%22https:////www.31sumai.com//%22,%22https:////www.31sumai.com//mfr//K1503//%22,%22https:////www.31sumai.com//mfr//K1503//%22,%22http:////maps.google.com//maps?q=34.69465,135.519178%22,%22https:\/\/www.31sumai.com\/mfr\/K1503\/juko.htm]`
```

Here is the controller codes:

```
$estates = Estates::get(); 

$data['estates'] = $estates; 
return view('welcome', $data);
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: what is the output of `$estate->link`?

Comment: I added the output at the bottom of the question.

Comment: I think your Url is not proper json encoded data.

Comment: share dump  of `var_dump(json_decode($estate->link));`

Comment: Is this `var_dump(json_decode($estate->link))` array ?

Comment: Can you also share your controller code please?

Comment: I update my question with my controller codes. Also before I insert links in database, yes it was an array. After that, I used json_encode and sent it. (I used json encode becouse some array to string conv error popped up.

Comment: Quick question what do you want to display . I might have a different work around if you just want to display a table

Comment: I want to display soft URL link which is json_encoded. Do you want to see my scraping data and insert way of data?

Comment: Did you print out $hrefs anywhere?

Comment: nope I didn't..